# Template matching counting error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, python

I ran this code to check the number of common instances found, with the template there. There should be 7 matches, but it shows only 4 and when I tried printing the count it shows 21 when the code is run. I understand that because of the threshold > 0.8 it returns 21. But is there a way that can be avoided, the multiple counting of the same template? Also, how can I detect the other 3 templates too?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('tempsearch.jpg')
template=cv2.imread('temptemp.jpg')

r,c,s=template.shape

res=cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
thresh=0.8
count=0
loc=np.where(res>thresh)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img , pt , (pt[0]+c , pt[1]+r) , (0,255,0) , 2)
    count+=1
    #print(img[list(pt)])
    #cv2.imshow('img'+str(count),img[list(pt)]) 
cv2.imshow('det',img)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image:

[image: tempsearch.jpg]

Template:

[image: temptemp.jpg]

Comment: I think this is a similar problem to yours have a look. https://github.com/sreeram004/Count-the-number-of-Palm-Trees/blob/master/Count_Trees_Final.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your template has multiple possible matches for a single object and you only want the best match. In object detection this problem is often solved using [Non-Maximum Suppression](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/). In essence, you find all bounding boxes that overlap and take the one that has the highest score. That leaves you with one bounding box per matched object, assuming your thresholds are otherwise good.